# Changing opacity of KML file (with icon linked) fetched in the Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a solution for making the .kml file transparent in the Leaflet Map. The working code looks like this:

```
L.KML = L.FeatureGroup.extend({

initialize: function (kml) {
    this._kml = kml;
    this._layers = {};

    if (kml) {
        this.addKML(kml);
    }
},

addKML: function (xml) {
    var layers = L.KML.parseKML(xml);
    if (!layers || !layers.length) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        this.fire('addlayer', {
            layer: layers[i]
        });
        this.addLayer(layers[i]);
    }
    this.latLngs = L.KML.getLatLngs(xml);
    this.fire('loaded');
},

latLngs: []
});

 L.Util.extend(L.KML, {

parseKML: function (xml) {
    var style = this.parseStyles(xml);
    this.parseStyleMap(xml, style);
    var el = xml.getElementsByTagName('Folder');
    var layers = [], l;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (!this._check_folder(el[i])) { continue; }
        l = this.parseFolder(el[i], style);
        if (l) { layers.push(l); }
    }
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('Placemark');
    for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
        if (!this._check_folder(el[j])) { continue; }
        l = this.parsePlacemark(el[j], xml, style);
        if (l) { layers.push(l); }
    }
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('GroundOverlay');
    for (var k = 0; k < el.length; k++) {
        l = this.parseGroundOverlay(el[k]);
        if (l) { layers.push(l); }
    }
    return layers;
},

// Return false if e's first parent Folder is not [folder]
// - returns true if no parent Folders
_check_folder: function (e, folder) {
    e = e.parentNode;
    while (e && e.tagName !== 'Folder')
    {
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    return !e || e === folder;
},

parseStyles: function (xml) {
    var styles = {};
    var sl = xml.getElementsByTagName('Style');
    for (var i=0, len=sl.length; i<len; i++) {
        var style = this.parseStyle(sl[i]);
        if (style) {
            var styleName = '#' + style.id;
            styles[styleName] = style;
        }
    }
    return styles;
},

parseStyle: function (xml) {
    var style = {}, poptions = {}, ioptions = {}, el, id;

    var attributes = {color: true, width: true, Icon: true, href: true, hotSpot: true};

    function _parse (xml) {
        var options = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var e = xml.childNodes[i];
            var key = e.tagName;
            if (!attributes[key]) { continue; }
            if (key === 'hotSpot')
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < e.attributes.length; j++) {
                    options[e.attributes[j].name] = e.attributes[j].nodeValue;
                }
            } else {
                var value = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                if (key === 'color') {
                    options.opacity = parseInt(value.substring(0, 2), 16) / 255.0;
                    options.color = '#' + value.substring(6, 8) + 
   value.substring(4, 6) + value.substring(2, 4);
                } else if (key === 'width') {
                    options.weight = value;
                } else if (key === 'Icon') {
                    ioptions = _parse(e);
                    if (ioptions.href) { options.href = ioptions.href; }
                } else if (key === 'href') {
                    options.href = value;
                }
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('LineStyle');
    if (el && el[0]) { style = _parse(el[0]); }
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('PolyStyle');
    if (el && el[0]) { poptions = _parse(el[0]); }
    if (poptions.color) { style.fillColor = poptions.color; }
    if (poptions.opacity) { style.fillOpacity = poptions.opacity; }
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('IconStyle');
    if (el && el[0]) { ioptions = _parse(el[0]); }
    if (ioptions.href) {
        style.icon = new L.KMLIcon({
            iconUrl: ioptions.href,
            shadowUrl: null,
            anchorRef: {x: ioptions.x, y: ioptions.y},
            anchorType: {x: ioptions.xunits, y: ioptions.yunits}
        });
    }

    id = xml.getAttribute('id');
    if (id && style) {
        style.id = id;
    }

    return style;
   },

    parseStyleMap: function (xml, existingStyles) {
    var sl = xml.getElementsByTagName('StyleMap');

    for (var i = 0; i < sl.length; i++) {
        var e = sl[i], el;
        var smKey, smStyleUrl;

        el = e.getElementsByTagName('key');
        if (el && el[0]) { smKey = el[0].textContent; }
        el = e.getElementsByTagName('styleUrl');
        if (el && el[0]) { smStyleUrl = el[0].textContent; }

        if (smKey === 'normal')
        {
            existingStyles['#' + e.getAttribute('id')] = 
 existingStyles[smStyleUrl];
        }
    }

    return;
},

parseFolder: function (xml, style) {
    var el, layers = [], l;
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('Folder');
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (!this._check_folder(el[i], xml)) { continue; }
        l = this.parseFolder(el[i], style);
        if (l) { layers.push(l); }
    }
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('Placemark');
    for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
        if (!this._check_folder(el[j], xml)) { continue; }
        l = this.parsePlacemark(el[j], xml, style);
        if (l) { layers.push(l); }
    }
    el = xml.getElementsByTagName('GroundOverlay');
    for (var k = 0; k < el.length; k++) {
        if (!this._check_folder(el[k], xml)) { continue; }
        l = this.parseGroundOverlay(el[k]);
        if (l) { layers.push(l); }
    }
    if (!layers.length) { return; }
    if (layers.length === 1) { return layers[0]; }
    return new L.FeatureGroup(layers);
},

parsePlacemark: function (place, xml, style, options) {
    var h, i, j, k, el, il, opts = options || {};

    el = place.getElementsByTagName('styleUrl');
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        var url = el[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        for (var a in style[url]) {
            opts[a] = style[url][a];
        }
    }

    il = place.getElementsByTagName('Style')[0];
    if (il) {
        var inlineStyle = this.parseStyle(place);
        if (inlineStyle) {
            for (k in inlineStyle) {
                opts[k] = inlineStyle[k];
            }
        }
    }

    var multi = ['MultiGeometry', 'MultiTrack', 'gx:MultiTrack'];
    for (h in multi) {
        el = place.getElementsByTagName(multi[h]);
        for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            return this.parsePlacemark(el[i], xml, style, opts);
        }
    }

    var layers = [];

    var parse = ['LineString', 'Polygon', 'Point', 'Track', 'gx:Track'];
    for (j in parse) {
        var tag = parse[j];
        el = place.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            var l = this['parse' + tag.replace(/gx:/, '')](el[i], xml, opts);
            if (l) { layers.push(l); }
        }
    }

    if (!layers.length) {
        return;
    }
    var layer = layers[0];
    if (layers.length > 1) {
        layer = new L.FeatureGroup(layers);
    }

    var name, descr = '';
    el = place.getElementsByTagName('name');
    if (el.length && el[0].childNodes.length) {
        name = el[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    el = place.getElementsByTagName('description');
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < el[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            descr = descr + el[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue;
        }
    }

    if (name) {
        layer.on('add', function () {
            layer.bindPopup('<h2>' + name + '</h2>' + descr, { className: 
  'kml-popup'});
        });
    }

    return layer;
},

parseCoords: function (xml) {
    var el = xml.getElementsByTagName('coordinates');
    return this._read_coords(el[0]);
},

parseLineString: function (line, xml, options) {
    var coords = this.parseCoords(line);
    if (!coords.length) { return; }
    return new L.Polyline(coords, options);
},

parseTrack: function (line, xml, options) {
    var el = xml.getElementsByTagName('gx:coord');
    if (el.length === 0) { el = xml.getElementsByTagName('coord'); }
    var coords = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
        coords = coords.concat(this._read_gxcoords(el[j]));
    }
    if (!coords.length) { return; }
    return new L.Polyline(coords, options);
},

parsePoint: function (line, xml, options) {
    var el = line.getElementsByTagName('coordinates');
    if (!el.length) {
        return;
    }
    var ll = el[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.split(',');
    return new L.KMLMarker(new L.LatLng(ll[1], ll[0]), options);
},

parsePolygon: function (line, xml, options) {
    var el, polys = [], inner = [], i, coords;
    el = line.getElementsByTagName('outerBoundaryIs');
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        coords = this.parseCoords(el[i]);
        if (coords) {
            polys.push(coords);
        }
    }
    el = line.getElementsByTagName('innerBoundaryIs');
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        coords = this.parseCoords(el[i]);
        if (coords) {
            inner.push(coords);
        }
    }
    if (!polys.length) {
        return;
    }
    if (options.fillColor) {
        options.fill = true;
    }
    if (polys.length === 1) {
        return new L.Polygon(polys.concat(inner), options);
    }
    return new L.MultiPolygon(polys, options);
},

getLatLngs: function (xml) {
    var el = xml.getElementsByTagName('coordinates');
    var coords = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
        // text might span many childNodes
        coords = coords.concat(this._read_coords(el[j]));
    }
    return coords;
},

_read_coords: function (el) {
    var text = '', coords = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
        text = text + el.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
    }
    text = text.split(/[\s\n]+/);
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var ll = text[i].split(',');
        if (ll.length < 2) {
            continue;
        }
        coords.push(new L.LatLng(ll[1], ll[0]));
    }
    return coords;
},

_read_gxcoords: function (el) {
    var text = '', coords = [];
    text = el.firstChild.nodeValue.split(' ');
    coords.push(new L.LatLng(text[1], text[0]));
    return coords;
},

parseGroundOverlay: function (xml) {
    var latlonbox = xml.getElementsByTagName('LatLonBox')[0];
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        [
            latlonbox.getElementsByTagName('south')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            latlonbox.getElementsByTagName('west')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        ],
        [
            latlonbox.getElementsByTagName('north')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            latlonbox.getElementsByTagName('east')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        ]
    );
    var attributes = {Icon: true, href: true, color: true};
    function _parse (xml) {
        var options = {}, ioptions = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var e = xml.childNodes[i];
            var key = e.tagName;
            if (!attributes[key]) { continue; }
            var value = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            if (key === 'Icon') {
                ioptions = _parse(e);
                if (ioptions.href) { options.href = ioptions.href; }
            } else if (key === 'href') {
                options.href = value;
            } else if (key === 'color') {
                options.opacity = parseInt(value.substring(0, 2), 16) / 255.0;
                options.color = '#' + value.substring(6, 8) + value.substring(4, 6) + value.substring(2, 4);
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
    var options = {};
    options = _parse(xml);
    if (latlonbox.getElementsByTagName('rotation')[0] !== undefined) {
        var rotation = latlonbox.getElementsByTagName('rotation')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        options.rotation = parseFloat(rotation);
    }
    return new L.RotatedImageOverlay(options.href, bounds, {opacity: options.opacity, angle: options.rotation});
}

 });

 L.KMLIcon = L.Icon.extend({
options: {
    iconSize: [32, 32],
    iconAnchor: [16, 16],
},
_setIconStyles: function (img, name) {
    L.Icon.prototype._setIconStyles.apply(this, [img, name]);
    if( img.complete ) {
        this.applyCustomStyles( img )
    } else {
        img.onload = this.applyCustomStyles.bind(this,img)
    }

},
applyCustomStyles: function(img) {
    var options = this.options;
    this.options.popupAnchor = [0,(-0.83*img.height)];
    if (options.anchorType.x === 'fraction')
        img.style.marginLeft = (-options.anchorRef.x * img.width) + 'px';
    if (options.anchorType.y === 'fraction')
        img.style.marginTop  = ((-(1 - options.anchorRef.y) * img.height) + 1) + 'px';
    if (options.anchorType.x === 'pixels')
        img.style.marginLeft = (-options.anchorRef.x) + 'px';
    if (options.anchorType.y === 'pixels')
        img.style.marginTop  = (options.anchorRef.y - img.height + 1) + 'px';
}
 });


  L.KMLMarker = L.Marker.extend({
options: {
    icon: new L.KMLIcon.Default()
}
  });

    // Inspired by 
        https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator/tree/master/src
      L.RotatedImageOverlay = L.ImageOverlay.extend({
     options: {
    angle: 0
    },
    _reset: function () {
    L.ImageOverlay.prototype._reset.call(this);
    this._rotate();
    },
    _animateZoom: function (e) {
    L.ImageOverlay.prototype._animateZoom.call(this, e);
    this._rotate();
    },
    _rotate: function () {
    if (L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM) {
        // use the CSS transform rule if available
        this._image.style[L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM] += ' rotate(' + 
    this.options.angle + 'deg)';
        } else if (L.Browser.ie) {
        // fallback for IE6, IE7, IE8
        var rad = this.options.angle * (Math.PI / 180),
            costheta = Math.cos(rad),
            sintheta = Math.sin(rad);
        this._image.style.filter += ' 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod=\'auto expand\', M11=' +
            costheta + ', M12=' + (-sintheta) + ', M21=' + sintheta + ', M22=' + costheta + ')';
    }
},
getBounds: function () {
    return this._bounds;
      }
   });
      // ---------- end L.KML -----------------------------

           var myKML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
        '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
   xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
   xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">' +
  '<Document>' +
  '<GroundOverlay>' +
'<name>Coventry.tif</name>' +
'<description>http://localhost/testc/Coventry.tif</description>' +
'<Icon>' +
    '<href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>' +
    '<viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>' +
'</Icon>' +
'<color>55ffffff</color>' +
'<LatLonBox>' +
    '<north>52.39388512224325</north>' +
    '<south>52.39299906007814</south>' +
    '<east>-1.458241039649089</east>' +
    '<west>-1.460061203494303</west>' +
'</LatLonBox>' +
   '</GroundOverlay>' +
    '<GroundOverlay>' +
     '<name>Coventry2.tif</name>' +
     '<description>http://localhost/testc/Coventry.tif2</description>' +
     '<Icon>' +
    '<href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>' +
    '<viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>' +
    '<color>00ff6633</color>' +
     '</Icon>' +
      '<LatLonBox>' +
    '<north>52.39299906007814</north>' +
    '<south>52.39199906007814</south>' +
    '<east>-1.458241039649089</east>' +
    '<west>-1.460061203494303</west>' +
    '</LatLonBox>' +
   '</GroundOverlay>' +
  '</Document>' +
  '</kml>'; 


   parser = new DOMParser();
   kml = parser.parseFromString(myKML,"text/xml");
   track = new L.KML(kml);

  map.addLayer(track);
  const bounds = track.getBounds();
  map.fitBounds( bounds );


  sldOpacity.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('image-opacity').innerHTML = this.value;
  track.setStyle({fillOpacity: this.value});
 }
```

Whereas the 1st part code of the L.KML.js, that belongs to the leaflet-kml plugin  based here:

https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml

and can be attached as an internal script.

then an another section of the code must be inside ther main script. I am not convinced to the form. Here I have to separate each single line of the XML code, punctuating it line be line. 
Is it possible to make a direct fetch of the .kml file as per the code below:

```
 var track

var kml = fetch('Coventry.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");
            track = new L.KML(kml);
            //console.log(kml)

            //const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)
            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )
      });
```

in order to avoid typing each single line of the .kml file?

Comment: “_Here I have to separate each single line of the XML code, punctuating it line be line._” Can you [edit] your post and better explain what that means? Does it have to do with how `myKML` is parsed?